# Installing wxPython and 'getting gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found' error

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to install Pylot on my computer and am using the instructions from Pylots website. Their site asks you to install wxPython. When I try to from their provided resource I am getting thrown an error.

Here is Pylot's getting started guide: http://www.pylot.org/gettingstarted.html

It directs Linux users to install wxPython at number three on their list. I follow the resource they provide for installing wxPython (http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian) and get an error when I run their first line of code...

```
curl http://apt.wxwidgets.org/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

This is the error I am thrown...

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: apt.wxwidgets.org
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Can anyone help me get Pylot up and running? I am having a terrible time with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname `apt.wxwidgets.org` is an invalid host.

```
$ host ping http://apt.wxwidgets.org/ 
host: couldn't get address for 'http://apt.wxwidgets.org/': not found
```

The latest supported Ubuntu version was Ubuntu 11.04.

Depending on your Ubuntu version, install `python-wxgtk2.8` or `python-wxgtk2.6` from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.6
```

**or**

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

Comment: It says that I already have 2.8 on my system.

Comment: Great, nothing to do for you